# Getting user input in javascript without using prompt

Tags: javascript, user-input

I have a setup where I allow the user to type commands in a regular html textfield. I handle the onkeypress event on the textfield, check if it is an enter key that has been pressed, and parse and execute the command.

An example could be:

```
deletefile /testfolder/testfile.html
```

The code kind of looks like this:

```
inputControl.onkeypress = function(e) { 
    if (e.which == 13) { 
        var outputMessage = commandHandler.executeCommand(inputControl.value);
        printOutputToScreen(outputMessage);
        inputControl.value = "";
        inputControl.focus();
    }
}
```

(by the way this is not what my code actually looks like, it's just an example)

The idea here is to be able to write a command, see the output, write another command, see the output, etc.

executeCommand parses the commandstring and calls a specific command with the appropriate arguments.

```
> deletefile /test1.html
The file was deleted

> deletefile /test2.html
An error occured while trying to delete the file
```

This part is simple. What I need help with is this: If the user just types "deletefile", I want to be able to ask the user (using the outputarea) "Which file do you want to delete?".

I know I can do this with:

```
var additionalInput = prompt("Which file?");
```

, but I don't want to use the prompt.

Forgetting about my contrived example, does anyone know of a good way of asking the user for input in the middle of a javascript (not using prompt), like:

```
var status = doSomeStuff(args);  
if (status.fail) {
    tmp = getUserInput();  
    doSomeFinalStuffBasedOnTheUserInput(tmp);
}
```

Is this even possible?

I'm not sure I'm able to explain myself here, but if anyone feel they can help me in some way please let me know :-)

One solution could be to implement a global state variable and use this as a mechanism in the keypress-eventhandler to route the input to the command, something like:

```
inputControl.onkeypress = function(e) {
  if (e.which == 13) {
      if (state.additionalInputPending && currentCommand != null) {
          currentCommand.executeWithAdditionalInput();
      } else {
          // perform regular command execution
      }
  }
}
```

In this way my "app" needs to handle in internal state variable, and store the currentCommand between keypresses.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a jquery/javascript solution where you show a 'fancy' dialog (not a JS prompt) to ask for the input.

http://trentrichardson.com/Impromptu/#Examples  The very last example shows forms.  Impromptu is just one of many (many, many) solutions for dialogs/prompt alternatives.

The only other option that comes to mind is to do it directly in the JS console you're creating more like a real command-line tool.

Comment: Yes, what I'm looking for is a solution that would mimic a command-line tool. My current setup is stateless, so I have no way of routing the additional info to my previous failed command execution attempt. I know the old-school text adventures had this capability:  
`> take  
>> What do you want to take?
> The red book  
>>Book taken` (I'm unable to add line-breaks)

Comment: You should create a 'stack' or an input variable of sorts to keep track and only execute when a full command is created.  It's similar to what you did above.  If status fails, then get additional input, and then call doSomeStuff again.  If fails again, ask for more inputs until complete.  To pull this off, you just need to keep track of old args and merge in new args.  And if they cancel (ctrl+c for example) then just throw away your args and re-prompt.  It should be a pretty simple workflow.